# program said no default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

Im trying to write a program that when the user enters a keyword for a movie the program search it in the title and comes back with the result. I am stuck on how to try to do that . i keep getting a error about not having a default constructor in the header class. i am not sure how to fix this.

this is the header class

```
// Movies.h
#ifndef MOVIES_H
#define MOVIES_H
#include "Movie.h" // include Movie class definition
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Movies {
// data is private by default
static const int MAX_MOVIES = 1000;
Movie movies[MAX_MOVIES];
int movieCnt;

public:
Movies(string);
void Test(string);
const Movie getMovie(int);


private:

void loadMovies(string);
string myToLower(string);
};
#endif
```

This is the cpp file for the header

```
// Movies.cpp
#include "Movie.h" // include Movie class definition
#include "Movies.h" // include Movies class definition
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

 Movies::Movies(string fn){loadMovies(fn);}


 const Movie Movies::getMovie(int mc) {
return movies[mc-1];
}

void Movies::loadMovies(string fn) {
ifstream iS(fn);
string s;
getline(iS, s); // skip heading
getline(iS, s);
movieCnt=0;
while(!iS.eof()) {
    movies[movieCnt++] = Movie(s);
    getline(iS, s);
}
iS.close();
}

 void Movies::Test(string key)
{
Movies[1];
}

string Movies::myToLower(string s) {
int n = s.length();
string t(s);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    t[i] = tolower(s[i]);
return t;
```

}

Here is my main function

```
// MovieInfoApp.cpp
#include "Movie.h" // include Movie class definition
#include "Movies.h" // include Movies class definition
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void main() {
Movies movies("Box Office Mojo.txt");
string answer, key;
bool set = false; 
int movieCode, ant;
cout<< "Would you like to start the Movie search?";
cin>> answer;
while (answer =="y" ||answer =="Y")
{
    cout<< "would you like to enter a movie name or a movie number? (press 1      for movie name press 2 for number";
    cin>>ant;
    if (ant = 2)
    {

        cout << "Please enter the movie number: ";
        cin >> movieCode;
        Movie m = movies.getMovie(movieCode);
        if(m.getTitle().length() > 0)
        {
            cout << m.toString() << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n Movie not found!\n\n" << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (ant =1)
    {   
        cout << "Please enter a keyword or title of the movie: ";
        cin >> key;
        Movies tester; // No default constructor error over here 
        tester.Test(key);
    }
    else 
    {
        cout<< "invalid entry please try again";
    }
    cout<< "Would you like to continute the Movie search?";
    cin>> answer;
}

}
```

Comment: Dont try to use a default ctor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to declare `tester` with the default constructor, and you have `Movie movies[1000]` which uses the default constructor, but there is no default constructor for your class.

You'll need to provide an argument for `tester` or define a default constructor.

For the array, even if you do define a default constructor so that it works, I recommend not using arrays that will be stored directly in the object because then your objects are really huge (and perhaps surprise you with an unexpected stack overflow). Use `std::vector` and that will take care of multiple problems.

Comment: so if i put this Movietest(); under the Movies(string);will that work ?

Comment: @BrianChiem if you want to define a default constructor, it should be `Movies();` under `Movies(string)`. And then you must define it too.

Answer (score 3):

The error is at clear as it can get - you have no default constructor. FYI, a default constructor is one that can be called without any arguments.

```
Movies tester;
```

will attempt to call a default constructor. You defined a non-default one - `Movies(string);`, so the compiler no longer generates a default one for you.

Comment: so what can i do to fix this? im not sure how to define a constructor?

Comment: You already defined a constructor (`Movies(string)`), so just define another one that doesn't require any arguments.